# Accessing component variables from methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

In my app, I have a component with a state variable and a component variable in its constructor. However, if I try accessing them from my method by resizing the window, I get `undefined` and `cannot read property 'test' of undefined`.

```js
import React from 'react';

class Testapp extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {test: "he"};
        this.test = "hu";
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.testCallback);
    }

    testCallback() {
        console.log(this.test);
        console.log(this.state.test);
    }

    render() {
        return( <p>Hello world</p> );
    }
}

export default Testapp;
```

How can I access these attributes from the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function as is does not have access to the `this` variable in the correct context.

The easiest solution is to convert to an arrow function

```js
testCallback = () => {
  console.log(this.test);
  console.log(this.state.test);
}
```

This will give your function the correct context of `this`.

Alternatively you could manually `bind` it in your constructor.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {test: "he"};
  this.test = "hu";
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.testCallback);
  this.testCallback = this.testCallback.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Ohhh, because a non-arrow-function already has its on `this`-context, right?

Comment: Here is a good answer that can explain things much better than I can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Answer (score 0):

Just use an arrow function instead. Alternatively, you can bind 'this' to the method.